# Secure browsing is not supported in my app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, https, facebook-php-sdk

I have an old application that I'd like to get running again. I've updated the Facebook PHP-sdk to the latest version (I think) and everything is working for most users. Except those using secure browsing.

My app simply tell me that:

```
This application does not yet support secure browsing (HTTPS).
```

How do I fix this? I've looked though all the settings in the app-page and I can't figure it out.

Comment: does your server allow ssl connections?

Comment: Yes it does, but I don't have ssl set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to purchase and setup an SSL certificate and then plug your https url into your app's settings page.  See their [migration guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/) where it says this is now required.