# My old app on FB doesn't work

Tags: facebook, https

I've got a problem with my old app and would like to know how to fix it. I found some advices, but I don't understand them. I need step-by-step instructions.

When I open my app: http://apps.facebook.com/ako-dobre-poz-jeadci/ it says: "This application does not yet support secure browsing (HTTPS)."

And when I open my app with turned off secure browsing, it says: "The app "Ako dobre poznáš Miša P.?" is temporarily unavailable due to an issue with its third-party developer. We are investigating the situation and apologize for any inconvenience."

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your posts. Probably there is a solution, but it's difficult for me. I'm not well IT educated.

Answer (score 3):

Your app has to support https. They sent out notifications for this about 6 months ago.

As mentioned in the comments, you probably also need to [migrate to OAuth 2.0](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/).

You really have to keep on top of your facebook apps, as they are notorious for quickly deprecating and removing API components. To put it bluntly, you got Zucker punched.

Comment: actually, it doesn't, non-secure version should display for all users who don't have secure browsing enabled in their Facebook user settings - i.e. there's something else wrong with the app

Comment: This, however is not likely to be the cause of the second message, which if the app is old is probably because they're not supporting Oauth 2.0 correctly - for example [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/fb_sig/#migrate) explains how to move to oauth 2.0 for canvas apps which were using the old auth mechanisms

Comment: I can't find the article now (facebook is blocked at my office), but all apps have to support https.

Comment: yes, they must support https to display for all users, but if you use any (e.g. http://) url for the https it will work for non-https users correctly

Comment: I haven't used this app for more than a year. How can I move to Oauth 2.0? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the settings in your app to supply an https URL.  I created a very nice step by step guide that takes you through this and many other setup steps, setting up a Java WebService, Persistence, and registering for FREE web hosting (that you can use for your https address), resulting in a completed demo App with some sample FB calls.  Goes from absolute 0 to fully functioning FB app with this 3 part blog series (part 1 starts here):

http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/creating-a-facebook-app-setup-and-tool-installation/

Answer (score 0):

Your app (and all of its resources) needs to be hosted on a secured domain (e.g.: https://www.example.com) with a valid SSL certificate

Comment: Your hosting provider likely has an SSL wizard that you can follow to have SSL set up for your domain.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix it, you have to buy and setup an SSL certificate. (it is now required since 1 October 2011 : [News](http://www.wpcode.net/fb-ssl.html/))
After, you have to add your https url in your app settings. 
Check Facebook authentification guide for dev for more information about it: 
[Authentification Guide - Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase and setup an SSL certificate and then plug your https url into your app's settings page. See their [migration guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/) where it says this is now required.

Source: [Secure browsing is not supported in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603127/secure-browsing-is-not-supported-in-my-app).

Comment: Go to www.paypal.com and see there's a small locker near the browser address bar. The address in the address bar is https:// instead of http:// that means it's secured, encrypted and trusted. You need to get yourself something similar to that, but it may be or it may not be simple (depending on where you host the application). I think this one's for ServerFault but I'm not sure.